How long without power can an SSD go before it can't be reformatted/reused?
I'm familiar with questions like Lifespan of an SSD (NAND Flash) for minimal write use archive purposes: Write once, toss in (proverbial or literal) storage closet and various media articles stating similar (in general, data retention is expected up to about a year), but they all concern how long an SSD can retain data. And unfortunately, my searches are only returning answers for that question.
My question is this: how long can an SSD remain unpowered before it can't be reformatted or otherwise reused? And, near that limit, do I need to take additional steps before I can reformat?
Context: I have an SSD that's been without power for well over a year. Obviously, I don't expect the stored data to survive, but I'd be reformatting it anyways even if it did, and it doesn't itself contain any sensitive data. However, it's been in temperature-controlled storage in a very dry place the whole time.

I suspect it'd just work - maybe even retain data with no issues. There may be variables like potentially the type of nand, and well, potential failure of the drive. If something does fail, chances are it isn't something trivially software fixable

It's iffy -- depends on the make and model of SSD, temperature, exposure to radiation... Even within one model, there might be an SSD where data survives many years, and one that loses it sooner. As Bob Newhart states, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ojgXwj40lo, "Some of 'em go down like a rock. And, I don't know, for some reason or other, others'll stay up for two, three minutes." That said, they could not be stocked on shelves for years and then sold if the basic drive OS did not survive.

I think the answer is going to be "it depends". Even in cases where lifespans are well understood, failure rates are bathtub shaped, and there is always the chance that well into the upward re-curve of the shape applicable to your own device, your specific device will either avoid the coming failure, or it will have long since died. Finally, I think your attempt to make a distinction between your own Q and the Lifespan Q fails: Being able to read and write are generally well linked, and the maximum age for recovering data should be the same as the maximum age for use of the drive.

This question is similar to: Lifespan of an SSD (NAND Flash) for minimal write use archive purposes: Write once, toss in (proverbial or literal) storage closet. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@DrMoishePippik Could you make that into an answer so I could accept it?

@music2myear SSDs may use different types of storage media for their main storage (which is always NAND flash) and their controller's firmware (which could be in longer-lasting NOR flash or even hardwired directly in silicon). Also, writes to NAND flash on a basic technical level don't depend on the ability to read existing data - they simply set the cells' bit lines to the right values and then raise the desired write lines to program the data to write. The voltage inside the cell doesn't matter when writing to NAND flash. (I'm oversimplifying, but this is all that's relevant to this.)

It's iffy -- depends on the make and model of SSD, temperature, exposure to radiation... Even within one model, there might be an SSD where data survives many years, and one that loses some of it sooner. As Bob Newhart states, "Some of 'em go down like a rock. And, I don't know, for some reason or other, others'll stay up for two, three minutes."
That said, SSD's could not be stocked on shelves, unconnected for years, and then sold if the basic firmware and file system did not survive.
In summary, you might lose some data on SSD more quickly than on magnetic media -- or not. However, it is unlikely an SSD would become unusable, i.e., impossible to format, just sitting on a shelf for a few years.

In terms of reformatting and reuse, SSDs are typically still functional after being unpowered for over a year. The concern with unpowered storage usually relates more to data retention rather than the ability to reformat or reuse the drive.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
